# User is not authorized to perform lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am following the aws tutorial on how to create thumbnails using lambda. I run this command to create a function:

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name CreateThumbnailDev --zip-file fileb://lambda-dev.zip --handler index.handler --runtime nodejs12.x --timeout 10 --memory-size 1024 --role arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/<MY_ROLE>
```

MY_ROLE is a role a created for executing lambda. The above command returns this error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:user/MY_USER is not authorized to perform: lambda:CreateFunction .....
```

the problem is that XXXXXXXXXXXXX is my account id (as the tutorial says to use if) but user/MY_USER is the user I configured my AWS CLI locally, it exists but it doesn't have the necessary policy attached.

How should I configure the client to execute this command?

Comment: _it exists but it doesn't have the necessary policy attached._
  You seem to have answered your own question. Is there some reason you cannot add the necessary policy to your user?

Comment: @AliSamji aws docs doesn't say I need to to it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html

Comment: That tutorial — like many others on the AWS docs — makes the assumption that you have more than a passing familiarity with AWS and that you would add the necessary permissions once you get the AccessDenied error.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have two different principals:

- Role associated to the lambda function: permissions that the lambda function itself will have
- Policies associated to your IAM user: what you can do

Looks like your IAM user named `MY_USER`, the one you're using for creating the lambda, is missing permissions for that. You'll need to grant them, either attaching a policy directly to the user or adding the user to a group that has the policies

You can [check the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_id-based) for that

Comment: Thanks @alberto I was asking because the tutorial I am following doesn't mention it. I'll try this way.

Comment: I attached the policy to the user but still same result. As I mentioned the tutorial doesn't say to do that so I am quite surprise with this error. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html

Comment: I also created a new user and attached AWSLambda_FullAccess and configured aws cli with it. same result.

Comment: The IAM principal you are using to deploy the Lambda function (presumably your IAM user) needs iam:PassRole permission for the role you are assigning to the Lambda function. Otherwise privilege escalation can occur.

Comment: @user3174311 Does the error message list the same action as in your question — `lambda:CreateFunction`? Are you doing this in your personal account or a company account?

Comment: thanks @jarmod, I solved adding IAMFullAccess as you suggested.